# Adding items to Unity's global menu bar for a pure X11 application

Tags: c, linux, gtk, x11, ubuntu-unity

My application is written using pure X11 APIs only, i.e. no GTK, qt or any other middleware. Everything is done via the low-level Xlib API, e.g. XCreateWindow() and so on. Is it possible to add items to Unity's global menu bar from a pure X11 application or would this force me to  do all window and event loop handling using a toolkit like GTK? I'd really like to stick with my current pure X11-based implementation but it would be nice if it was somehow possible to add a few menu items to Unity's global menu bar for my application.

Comment: [Related](http://askubuntu.com/questions/98692/how-to-add-support-for-the-global-menu-to-a-python-non-gtk-non-qt-app).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display menu each time some toplevel window is focused you need to call `com.canonical.AppMenu.Registrar.RegisterWindow` method of  `/com/canonical/AppMenu/Registrar` passing window id and your menu path ( your string id, which is also a service name - usually build using some path and win id ). Then you need to implement `com.canonical.dbusmenu` interface on that service name - namely, `GetLayout`, `GetGroupProperties`, `Event`, `AboutToShow` and `LayoutUpdated` methods.

I did simple library to implement all this in JavaScript using [node-dbus](https://github.com/sidorares/node-dbus) and [node-x11](https://github.com/sidorares/node-x11) libraries. See [example](https://github.com/sidorares/node-dbusmenu/blob/master/test/test-x11.js) which creates toplevel window and unity menu for it ( no glib / libdbus / libx11 dependencies here, pure networking )

Comment: Does not seem to work in 14.04 anymore - all unity apps use 'org.gtk.Menus' related interfaces. I'll post update once I know more details